# Batch Script IF-Then Statement for Reg Query

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So, I am right now creating a script for our VDI environment where it will create a registry entry on the HKEY_CURRENT_USER key, if the key does not exist. I have never done an if-then in batch, so I am curious how best to go about doing it. Right now my code is:

```
REG QUERY HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskbarAl

IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO INSTALL
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "TaskbarAl" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /reg:64
```

Not sure how best to do it, since this is the first batch script I've written with an if clause. But, basically if TaskbarAl doesn't exist, then add it to that directory.

I wrote out the above script, but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:bash] and [tag:powershell]?

Comment: If the key and value exists, there's no harm in just adding it with an overwrite, is there? i.e. ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "TaskbarAl" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL```. Or if the end user already has the registry key, and value, are you wanting their dword value to remain unmodified?

Comment: The TaskbarAl registry key is set to 0 so that way the taskbar gets put to the left side. It's Windows 11 and it's for Azure Virtual Desktop. No reason for users to be customizing their taskbar if it's not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

If, as per my comment, you want the key, value, and data, to be implemented regardless of whether it exists or not, then:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "TaskbarAl" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL
```

If you do want to add the value and data, only if the value does not already exist, *(keeping the end users data untouched)*, then:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /F "TaskbarAl" /V /E 2>NUL 1>&2 || %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "TaskbarAl" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 1>NUL
```

As you can see, no IF statement was required. I made use of a conditional statement using `||` instead. That condition means, if the previous command was unsuccessful, *(returned an error)*.

If you still wanted to use an IF, you could do that too:

```bash
@Echo Off
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /F "TaskbarAl" /V /E 2>NUL 1>&2
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Exit /B
Rem Your commands to install go here.
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V "TaskbarAl" /T REG_DWORD /D 0 1>NUL
```